# Can Java understand that threads which have same name are different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

In each iteration, a thread "student" is created. Because those threads are all named "student". Can Java understand that these are different thread?

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
    // open client socket to accept connection
    client = server.accept();
    System.out.println(client.getInetAddress()+" contacted ");
    System.out.println("Creating thread to serve request");

    ServerStudentThread student = new ServerStudentThread(client);
    student.start();
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Every thread has a name for identification purposes. **More than one thread may have the same name**. If a name is not specified when a thread is created, a new name is generated for it.

The JVM tracks threads by their ID, not by their name.

Comment: @skaffman, *The JVM tracks threads by their ID, not by their name* This Brutally Incorrect!! You mean if you override getId() and java does get messed up? Java tracks the threads by reference, not id (and some native code bijection)

Comment: @bestsss I believe skaffman refers to the id assigned by the native threading implementation and the getId() method being non final makes it an unlikely choice.

Comment: @josefx: Just so. It'd be interesting to see what would happen if you overrode `getId()`.

Comment: @skaffman, absoultely nothing happens, or well almost [if you override getId(), some poorly designed systems can be "hacked" by doing so since they recognize managing threads by ids, instead of weakRef; ReadWriteLock can be confused since it remembers last thread by the id, attempts an optimization]; Hotspot uses the FS (or was GS?, always forget) register (on x86) to point to local thread structure, so Thread.localThread is execute in few (6?) cpu clocks and it has nothing to do w/ the OS handle assigned to thread.

Comment: @skaffman, i think `eetop` is used to store the handle in hotspot but it was years since i looked at the code.